# Disable specific device when another device connects programatically

Tags: java, windows, device-driver

I have an issue where the keys on my Type Cover 2 on my Surface Pro 2 gets stuck after holding them down for 8 seconds. This is particularly annoying with to ctrl/shift/alt keys which often end up being held for a long time when editing images and so forth.

The [solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro2-surfhardware/sticking-keys-workaround/44f96c86-d653-407a-a694-86acfa53cda0) to the problem is to disable "Microsoft Input Configuration Device" in *Device Manager*, however, it as well has some drawbacks, as most of the touchpad gestures will no longer worker.

I therefore thought I'd see if it's possible to automatically disable said device (or device driver) when I connect an external mouse, like a BlueTooth mouse or whatever, and then revert the effect whenever it would disconnect.

Is this a somewhat non-trivial task? If not, which programming language should I pursue my goal in? I've listed Java as a tag as it's my go-to language of choice.

Disclaimer: I wasn't 100 % percent certain whether to post this on stackoverflow or programmers, or even serverfault. I figured I'd try here as I'm after a programming solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via [devcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx) - it's essentially a command line utility that allows you to control hardware (remove/disable/enable/rescan). The C source for this tool is in the WDK, so you could get it then wrap it in a DLL to use via JNA/I (or you could just make command line calls from Java to the devcon.exe itself).